# How to display multiple moving text in one line instead of multiple lines by marquee tag?

Tags: html, jinja2, marquee

```
{% for term in terms %}
    <marquee behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="1" > {{ term }}</marquee>
{% endfor %}
```

For example, if terms is:

```
terms = ['term1', 'term2', 'term3']
```

They are currently displayed vertically and moving to the right:

```
term1
term2
term3
```

But I hope them to be displayed at one line when moving:

```
term1 term2 term2
```

Is this possible with the marquee tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try

```css
.marquee-wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

marquee {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee-wrapper">
    <span>Recent Items: </span>
    <marquee style="background-color: yellow;" behavior="scroll" direction="right" scrollamount="1">
        <!-- {% for term in terms %}
            {{ term }}
        {% endfor %} -->
        Text to move
    </marquee>
</div>
```

Which will put all the texts in a single marquee, and it will be moving one after another.

**EDIT**

Added background-color to the marquee tag

**EDIT-2**

Added a text right before the marqee

Comment: That indeed worked! Is there a way to add some background color to the marquee area?

Comment: To the total marquee, yes, you can add `background-color: yellow;` to the tag

Comment: Yes. That works too. One last refinement: If I add the text 'recent terms:' before the marquee tag, it is displayed at another line. Can the added text be on the same line of these moving text, just right before the texts: recent terms: term1 term2 term2?

Comment: Yes, but you might need to wrap these two in a single parent tag, will update it in snippet.

Comment: Let me test. Probably I have to use another name for 'div', otherwise, it may affect other existing 'div' tag

Comment: Sure, give it a class name and use it. Kindly upvote and accept the answer if helps :)